# Date binding doesn't bind on current date

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, datepicker

when using `MinimumDate="{x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}"` in DatePicker, when creating new item and not chosing date (date should automatically select the current date) does not do so.

When not changing the date in collection view it defaults to 1/1/0001. Why is this?

It works fine when I do select a date (i.e when selecting 5/8/2022) this date will be displayed in the collectionview. Only when I do not select a date it will default to 1/1/0001.

NewItemViewModel.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using xamarinMobileTest.Models;

namespace xamarinMobileTest.ViewModels
{
    public class NewItemViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        private string text;
        private string description;
        private DateTime dueDate;

        public NewItemViewModel()
        {
            SaveCommand = new Command(OnSave, ValidateSave);
            CancelCommand = new Command(OnCancel);

            this.PropertyChanged +=
                (_, __) => SaveCommand.ChangeCanExecute();
        }

        private bool ValidateSave()
        {
            return !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text)
                && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(description);
        }

        public string Text
        {
            get => text;
            set => SetProperty(ref text, value);
        }

        public DateTime DueDate
        {
            get => dueDate;
            set => SetProperty(ref dueDate, value);
        }
        public string Description
        {
            get => description;
            set => SetProperty(ref description, value);
        }

        public Command SaveCommand { get; }
        public Command CancelCommand { get; }

        private async void OnCancel()
        {
            // This will pop the current page off the navigation stack
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..");
        }

        private async void OnSave()
        {
            Item newItem = new Item()
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                Text = Text,
                Description = Description,
                DueDate = DueDate
            };

            await DataStore.AddItemAsync(newItem);

            // This will pop the current page off the navigation stack
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to set the value to, MinimumDate is a property for errorhandling not value handling

Comment: How do I do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this, like i said minimum Date doesnt set the value

```
<DatePicker MinimumDate="{Binding MinDate}"
        MaximumDate="{Binding MaxDate}"
        Date="{Binding SelectedDate}" />
```

Your DueDate was not initiated, this means it takes the default value which is 0001/01/01

```
    /* ... */
    private DateTime dueDate;

    public NewItemViewModel()
    {
        DueDate = DateTime.Today;
        SaveCommand = new Command(OnSave, ValidateSave);
        CancelCommand = new Command(OnCancel);

        this.PropertyChanged +=
            (_, __) => SaveCommand.ChangeCanExecute();
    }

    /* .... */
```

Comment: I only need the minimum date as it is basically a "due date." How do I create the minDate in the viewmodel to be set to the current time?

Comment: Even when selecting the current date as the due date in my previous method, the 1/1/0001 outcome still came up. The only work around was selecting a different date then selecting the current date once again. Only then would it be seen in the collectionview as that date

Comment: @Tanner Could you post your getters and setters of your current model?

Comment: My ViewModel or..? - I don't have a date model